# the words "variant" and "option" are the same in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Are the words "variant" and "option" the same in the following context?

> "For the letter B there are two **variants** of pronunciation"

vs

> "For the letter B there are two **options** of pronunciation"

Comment: I would say *variant* indicates that there is some relationship between the items involved, while *options* are just any kind of choices. To answer your question, we need to know what the "two" items are.

Answer (score 1):

The nouns *variant* and *option*, while similar, actually imply different things.  An option suggests an available *choice*, while a variant suggests an existing *type*.  Examples:

> A military that wishes to purchase one of these helicopters can pick from one of the available **options**.
>
> There are many different **variants** of the helicopter, adapted by different militaries for different operational roles.

Both of your examples are awkward but acceptable. It just depends on what you are trying to say.  If you want to say a speaker has two *choices* about how to pronounce the letter "B", then use "option".  If instead you want to say that speakers commonly pronounce the letter "B" in two different ways, then use "variant".

That being said, "options of pronunciation" sounds unnatural.  ["For" seems the more natural preposition](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=options%20of%2C%20options%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3):

> There are three **options for** a traditional holiday dinner:  ham, beef, or turkey.

However, I prefer "choice" to "option" when talking about pronunciation, and I would avoid the preposition entirely:

> There are two **pronunciation choices** for the letter "B": ...

Or you can use "way":

> There are two **ways** we can pronounce the letter "B": ...

If you really want to use "variant", it's fine, but again I would avoid the unnecessary preposition:

> The letter "B" has two **pronunciation variants**: ...